# How to call a shell script from another shell script based on the first script's result?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Shell script 1.sh is like

```
#/bin/bash

if some java command;
then 
exit 1;
else    
exit 0;
fi
```

Shell script 2.sh will determine its execution based on the result (1 or 0) from 1.sh

```
#/bin/bash
readyToDoSomethingIfOne=$(1.sh)

if($readyToDoSomethingIfOne=="1");
then
echo "ready to go";
else    
echo "Not ready yet" ;
fi
```

It looks like exit command from 1.sh does not pass the value to 2.sh. Is there any good way to do so?

By the way, 1.sh and 2.sh have to be separated for business reasons.

Thanks

Comment: The exit status is `$?`, not captured in `$()` (which gets content sent to stdout). In general, though, if you wanted to know if something succeeded or not, you don't need to check `$?` explicitly -- `if some_command` will take the true branch if `$?` is 0 after running `some_command`, the else branch otherwise.

Comment: By the way, bash scripts shouldn't be named with `.sh` extensions -- first, commands don't conventionally have extensions at all in UNIX (you don't run `ls.elf`); second, bash is not POSIX sh, and someone running `sh foo.sh` rather than `bash foo.sh` would be in for an unwelcome surprise if you used any features not available in the barebones standard form of the language.

Comment: By the way, `exit 0` should be used on success, and `exit 1` on failure.

Answer (score 2):

```
#/bin/bash

if 1.sh; then
  echo "ready to go";
else    
  echo "Not ready yet" ;
fi
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, you need to say `if ! 1.sh` in order to _comply_ with OPs `return` _convention_.  (Take a look at OPs script 1; it returns with an exit code of 1 in case the command is successful `:)` )

Comment: @devnull, I'm going to leave this as-is, and upvote your comment. Better for the OP to fix their code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash
if readyToDoSomethingIfOne=$(1.sh); then # Just use the exit status of the initial script directly.
    …
else
    echo 'nope!'
fi
```

If you don't actually need the variable at all, just run the script like this:

```
if ./1.sh; then
  echo "Not ready yet"
  return / exit / continue # Not enough context to know which exit approach is best.
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct

```
VAR=$(COMMAND)
```

assigns the *output* of COMMAND to the variable VAR.  You can get the *exit status* of the last command from the automatic variable `$?`.  That is

```
COMMAND
case $? in
  0)
      # do this
      ;;
  1)
      # do that
      ;;
  *)
      # do something else
      ;;
esac
```

If you only want to distinguish between success (`$? == 0`) and failure (`$? != 0`) then you can use the simpler `if` construct as in your `script1.sh`.

If using `$?`, watch out that it changes after every command, so if you need the value for later use, save it in a variable.

```
COMMAND
status=$?
# now use $status
```